# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Card - Dark Mode Color Issue

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to develope a simple messagaging extension app for Microsoft Teams. With the use of Task Modules I can load a simple Adative Card. Works as designed. The only problem I have with it, is that my Adaptive Card has a color issue withing Microsoft Teams in Dark Mode.

Take a look at the image below. `1` shows a very simple Adaptive Card designed via https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ (preview mode). `2` the very same Adaptive Card but now an actual snippet from Microsoft Teams. As you can see the card below has some color issues which makes the input hard to see.

[image]

Here is the code I've used:

```js
public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTask(
    context: TurnContext,
    action: any
  ): Promise<any> {
    const adaptiveCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "size": "Medium",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "text": "${title}"
        },
        {
          "type": "Input.Text",
          "placeholder": "Placeholder text"
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "Action.Submit",
          "title": "Submit"
        }
      ],
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "version": "1.3"
    });

    return {
      task: {
        type: 'continue',
        value: {
          card: adaptiveCard,
          height: 535,
          title: '${title}',
          url: null,
          width: 500
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not much that can be done about the input box itself in this case, but maybe try changing the colour of the label above it, something like this (I've changed some of your property names as well, as they were invalid case - things like "medium" instead of "Medium":

```
          "size": "medium",
          "weight": "bolder",
          "text": "${title}",
          "color": "good"
```

`Color` allows the following values:
"default"
"dark"
"light"
"accent"
"good"
"warning"
"attention"

Answer (score 0):

If you nest your Text input into a Container, you are able change the Container's style to provide a coloured background upon which the Text input sits.

It's not necessarily right for your use case, but it could be a workaround of interest

[Container Style colour options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQLx9.png)

```js
{
    "type": "Container",
    "style": "emphasis",
    "bleed": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Request New Ticket",
            "wrap": true,
            "fontType": "Default",
            "style": "heading",
            "size": "Large",
            "color": "Good",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
        }
    ]
}
```